# Looking for a juvenile/ YA science fiction book about kids that are taken in a spaceship to fight an enemy, but soon discover the enemy doesn't exist

Tags: story-identification

I am looking for a juvenile/ YA science fiction book about kids that are taken to space (spaceship) to fight an enemy, but soon discover the enemy doesn't exist.

There is a door with scratches on it. I read around 2018-2020. Spoilers ahead.

**Details:**

- These kids get taken to space to fight an enemy they are told exists but they soon find out it is not real.
- There is a specific door with scratches on it though.
- The owner of the ship just wanted to stay in business so he made up a fake enemy.
- Oh, and a kid likes to travel through the vents.
- One kid gets taken straight out of their room.
- The parents of the kids get their memories erased.
- I believe there was a girl who was the daughter of the captain.
- I think the cover was dark. The cover had some dark greyish-green & the words were grey.
- The cover might have had a picture of a clawed-up door.
- I also remember that at one point they look out a huge window in the ship.
- Someone gets sent to the brig

Books that are **NOT** it:

- Tommy Storm
- Project Alpha
- The Exo Project
- Ender's Game
- Ender's Shadow

Comment: So, are spaceships commonplace in the setting, or is this more like kids being abducted from Earth by aliens/advanced humans? What do the kids do when they realize there's no enemy?

Comment: Also posted to https://www.goodreads.com/topic/show/22168074-juvenile-ya-science-fiction-kids-are-taken-to-space-spaceship-to-fig. Are some of the other details there still considered valid?

Comment: Sounds like it at least cribs heavily from Ender's Shadow by Orson Scott Card - it's not that book is it?

Comment: This reminded me of Ender's Game. But it's a movie and some details are off. Just sayin..

Comment: @polfosolఠ_ఠ [*Ender's Game*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ender%27s_Game) was a novel (1985) decades before it was a movie (2013).

Comment: @FuzzyBoots  I only remember there being the one spaceship.

Comment: @PatJ There was a movie?!?!?  I must have subconsciously deleted that from my memories!  Kinda like there is only 1 highlander movie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to a Fellow Goodreads Member I have found the book. **The Book Is "The Incredible Space Raiders from Space!" Written by Wesley King.**

**Book Summary:**

When Jonah wakes up on the Fantastic Flying Squirrel, he's a bit confused. One second he is in his family's living room doing his homework, and the next he's sitting on a very cold floor on a very cold ship with a very strange-looking girl staring at him. Her name is Willona the Awesome, and she's here to welcome him to The Incredible Space Raiders.

Now that Jonah is on board, the Incredible Space Raiders can set off on an important mission: to venture into the Dark Zone and save the universe from the Entirely Evil Things. But when Space Raiders start to disappear, Jonah realizes that if he's going to make it to the Dark Zone alive, he's going to have to step up and figure out what's going on.